# How to postion GroupBox ,DataGrid, and Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Im struggling to position a GroupBox, a DataGrid and a Menu from Top to Bottom.
So for the first approach I used the StackPanel (Pseudo XAML Code):

```
<StackPanel>
    <GroupBox/>
    <DataGrid/>
    <Menu/>
</StackPanel>
```

The problem is that I want the DataGrid to fill the rest of the space between the Groupbox and Menu and it keeps displaying like that:
[image]

I tried using the DockPanel:

```
<DockPanel>
   <GroupBox DockPanel.Dock = "Top"/>
   <DataGrid/>
   <Menu DockPanel.Dock = "Bottom"/>
</DockPanel>
```

It stretches the DataGrid well but the Menu is not positioned properly
[image]

Also in this case the DataGrid collapses after compilation
[image]

How should I do this so the elements display properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work - can't really give you a correct answer to why it works like this, but it has something to do with which components get created first whenever you are using docking. So by placing menu above the datagrid, your dockpanel works as you described.

Please someone correct me if i'm mistaking. Still learning about this myself.

```
<DockPanel>
    <GroupBox Header="Filter" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="Label 1" />
        <Label Content="Label 2" />
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <MenuItem Header="Menu 1">

        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Menu 2">

        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header1" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header2" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header3" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header4" Width="*" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</DockPanel>
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope... Still the same problem. The Datagrid doesn't want to fill the space.. Looks ok in the designer but after running the app it is still collapsed.

Comment: It works for me, could there be any other containers/panels which handles the streching of your controls for you? 

If you could provide some code, it would be easier to see which problems you are running into.

my exampel is just in a window with the height of 300 and width of 300.

Comment: Yeah it works thank you :) The problem was that I had a `TabControl` above those with `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` not set to `Stretch`

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" />
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" />
    <Menu Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick response

Comment: But still the DataGrid doesn't fill the rest of the space

Comment: It does fill the whole space but there is no data for DataGrid control so what do you expect it to display?